# MSSQL Unexpected output of the binary field in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xslt, mssql-jdbc

I tried to get a `binary(16)` for my XSLT Project in a XML File to transformat it.

Here is, what I tried:

```
SELECT BINARY_ID FROM dbo.MyTable

SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(16), BINARY_ID) AS BINARY_ID  FROM dbo.MyTable

SELECT CAST(BINARY_ID AS varbinary(20)) AS BINARY_ID FROM dbo.MyTable

SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), BINARY_ID) AS BINARY_ID  FROM dbo.MyTable

SELECT CAST(BINARY_ID AS binary(20)) AS BINARY_ID FROM dbo.MyTable
```

What ever I tried, my `BINARY_ID` changed from `0x00D25E18AEFF4979A244C2EB132791C1` to `ANJeGK7/SXmiRMLrEyeRwQ==`

I am using a JDBC Connector for the Connection and to get the Data from the Database.

I'm starting to have no idea, what my problem cause.

Is my project possible at all or do I have to combine it with something else to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

UPDATE

---

Here is my XSLT Script which is powered over a Java compiler in to a JDBC Connector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:output media-type="text/xml" method="xml"></xsl:output>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <statement format="yyyy-MM-dd' 'hh:mm" resulttag="object_II" timezone="UTC">
        <sql>
            SELECT
                AD.GGUID,
                AD.COMPNAME AS Firmen_Name_1,
                AD.COMPNAME2 AS Firmen_Name_2,
                AD.GWBRANCH AS Branche,
                AD.COUNTRY1 AS Land,
                AD.STREET1 AS Straße,
                AD.ZIP1 AS PLZ,
                AD.TOWN1 AS Ort,
                AD.GWSTATE1 AS Bundesland,
                AD.PHONEFIELDSTR10 AS Telefon_Nr,
                AD.MAILFIELDSTR5 AS EMail
            FROM dbo.TABLE_I AS CL
            inner join dbo.TABLE_II AS AD ON AD.GGUID = CL.TABLEGUID
                Where CL.TABLENAME = 'ADDRESS'
                    AND CL.FIELDNAME = 'CHECKBOX'
                    AND AD.CHECKBOX= 1
                    AND AD.UPDATETIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -60, SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME()
            Order BY ad.GGUID DESC
        </sql>
    </statement>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `ANJeGK7/SXmiRMLrEyeRwQ==` isn't a `varbinary` value, so your bottom 2 queries can't return that value. What is the actual problem here? What isn't working? Sample data and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me xD I get a Binary ID in my DB which is`0x00D25E18AEFF4979A244C2EB132791C1` and thats what I want to get. But what I get instad is ANJeGK7/SXmiRMLrEyeRwQ==. I also tried the `convert(binary(16)` and `cast(... AS binar(16))` Too mut nothing worked....

Comment: If `BinaryID` has a value of `0x00D25E18AEFF4979A244C2EB132791C` then `SELECT BinaryID` is going to return that value... As for `CONVERT(varbinary(16), binaryID)` is `binaryID` is already a `binary` value (which I *assume* it is based on it's name and lack of information otherwise) then the `CONVERT` will do nothing. It is **impossible** for a `binary` to return the value `'ANJeGK7/SXmiRMLrEyeRwQ=='` as that isn't a `binary` value, it's an `(n)varchar`.

Comment: On MSSQL Studio it is but not in my JDBC Project... Thats my problem I treid diffrent binary ID's too and the reault is the same

Comment: Then show us the code from your project, the SQL doesn't have anything to do with the problem here.

Comment: I wrote an Update. The GGUID is my BINARY_ID

Comment: @Larnu, the given string value is the Base64 representation of a binary value... See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the function `varbintohexstring()` is limited... I'd use `CONVERT()` here.

In the beginning a HEX-string was the default format for embedding binaries within XML. With v2005 this was changed to Base64 as it can represent a binary value with less characters.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @someGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

SELECT @someGuid AS TheGuid
      ,CAST(@someGuid AS BINARY(16)) binValue_Base64
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),CAST(@someGuid AS BINARY(16)),1) binValue_HexString
FOR XML PATH('test');
```

The result

```
<test>
  <TheGuid>67D4B263-CEDC-4164-AA32-B7F8F6DCA946</TheGuid>
  <binValue_Base64>Y7LUZ9zOZEGqMrf49typRg==</binValue_Base64>
  <binValue_HexString>0x63B2D467DCCE6441AA32B7</binValue_HexString>
</test>
```

The idea in short:

- You seem to talk about a GUID, but the following holds true for any other value.
- The GUID is a very special type of value, as it is a binary but uses its very special format for representation.
- Within XML, which is a text based container, any value must be represented by *printable characters* (well, not talking about entities here...)
- Casting a GUID to BINARY(16) will lead to a Base64 encoded value in XML.
- But you can use `CONVERT()` to cast a BINARY to VARCHAR, which will result in a HEX string [Read the section *binary styles* for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Both **string** values can be re-translated to the original GUID (`67D4B263-CEDC-4164-AA32-B7F8F6DCA946`):

```
  DECLARE @base64 VARCHAR(25)='Y7LUZ9zOZEGqMrf49typRg==';

  SELECT CAST(@base64 AS xml).value('.','binary(16)') Base64_as_binary
        ,CAST(CAST(@base64 AS xml).value('.','binary(16)') AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) TheOriginalGuid

  DECLARE @HexString VARCHAR(25)='0x63B2D467DCCE6441AA32B7';

  SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16),@HexString,1) Hex_as_binary
        ,CAST(CONVERT(BINARY(16),@HexString,1) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) TheOriginalGuid
```

Comment: So fare so good but how can I use this now dynamic? I tried now many ways and it went wrong every time. I tried to get the GUID as variable and convert it then but it won't work with the `@base64` example. The resault is empty.

Comment: @RyffLe,  What is the actual data type of `GGUID` and what does it represent?

Comment: @RyffLe, just to prove, that the result you've got (in your question) try this: `DECLARE @YourBase64 VARCHAR(25)='ANJeGK7/SXmiRMLrEyeRwQ=='; SELECT CAST(@YourBase64 AS XML).value('.','binary(16)')`. There are various ways to translate between binary and base64...

Comment: @Ryffle If your `GGUID` is of type `binary` actually, it should be enough to use `CONVERT(varchar(25),GGUID,1)` in order get the HEX-string...

Comment: I tried it in my XSLT Project and the resault is the same as in my Question. But `CONVERT(varchar(25),GGUID,1)` seems like to work :) Thanks.

Comment: @RyffLe, nice to read... Using this `CONVERT()` does roughly the same as your approach with `fn_varbintohexstring()`, just in an *official* way...

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by my own by using the master function varbintohexstr

Here is my complete MSSQL Statement.

```
            SELECT
                UPPER(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(AD.GGUID)) AS GGUID,
            FROM dbo.TABLE_I AS CL
            inner join dbo.TABLE_II AS AD ON AD.GGUID = CL.TABLEGUID
                Where CL.TABLENAME = 'ADDRESS'
                    AND CL.FIELDNAME = 'Checkbox'
                    AND AD.Checkbox = 1
                    AND AD.UPDATETIMESTAMP BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -960, SYSDATETIME()) AND SYSDATETIME()
            Order BY ad.GGUID DESC
```

RESAULT:

```
0X00D25E18AEFF4979A244C2EB132791C1
```